# Improve HttpResponseMessage performance with async task

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, async-await

I am implementing in the controller of **C# Framework 4.7.2 API** a method that must be asynchronous to unblock the thread (as mentioned in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net) article) of a heavy process so that the service can continue to serve requests from other clients, and when that process finishes return a response.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Method")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Method()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage task = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            // response.Content...
            return response;
        });
        return task;
    }
```

The reason I have decided to do the asynchronous method is to improve performance. Are there other possible solutions?

Comment: I am using Task.Run because the code that runs inside the task is synchronous, so I could not do an await otherwise.

Comment: Could you replace the `// response.Content...` comment with the actual code that is placed there?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I don't think it is relevant, there are only calls to third party libraries that generate a document that is returned to the client.

Comment: How do these third party libraries interact with the [`HttpResponseMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage) instance? Something looks strange here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misinterpreting that guidance.

Your method is synchronous, and `Task.Run` is effectively mocking asynchronous behaviour by offloading the work to a Thread Pool thread.

In an ASP.Net context, that thread is coming from the pool that is used to serve other requests, so whilst you are unblocking the current thread and releasing it back to the pool, you are instead borrowing another thread to do the work.

This thread switching does not make any more threads available, but does introduce unnecessary overhead.

What is the solution?

Well, removing the call to `Task.Run` will introduce a slight performance improvement, but if your service does experience throughput issues you could persist the request to a queue to be picked up by another process, allowing your `Method` to return early and keep your API reponsive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Johnathan Barclay I was misinterpreting that guide. The solution you propose seems good to me, but in case all the threads were busy and more requests were coming in to the service, probably queuing them would also impact the response time. Are there other possible solutions to this problem?

Comment: I will rephrase this question to help more people in this situation.

Comment: @david.q: If one thread is handling one request, then other threads can handle other requests. ASP.NET is multithreaded by default, so there's no queueing there unless the thread pool is overwhelmed with requests.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Stephen Cleary, then there is no other possibility than to make the request lighter so that the threads can not be blocked and can serve more customers, am I right? By the way, thanks for your work on the guide and your blog, I find it very useful.

Comment: @david.q: CPU-heavy web services are unusual, so it might be helpful to tweak the ASP.NET thread pool settings. But at the end of the day, CPU-heavy web services are just not going to scale well on a single machine, and you'll need to scale out to serve more customers.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your code execution is synchronous marking it async for the sake of it may not make a lot of sense.

However if it is a must to have async endpoint even for synchronous operations, you could use `await Task.FromResult(resultObject);` or its void variant `await Task.CompletedTask`. This would make your code like:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Method")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Method()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    // response.Content...        
    return await Task.FromResult(response);
}
```

Also [look at this link from MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2011/october/asynchronous-programming-async-performance-understanding-the-costs-of-async-and-await#asynchronicity-and-performance) for further details